# on lid suspend blank screen and irq messages on two lines

Tags: suspend, lockup

the messages are also in the journal.
[drm:dal_irq_service_dummy_ack [amdgpu]] *ERROR* dal_irq_service_dummy_ack: called for non-
implemented irq source, src_id=0, ext_id=0

[drm:dal_irq_service_dummy_set [amdgpu]] *ERROR* dal_irq_service_dummy_set: called for non-implemented irq source, src_id=0, ext_id=0

Asus ryzen 5 20.4.1   wayland  5.19.0-46-generic

if it keeps up I will clonezilla back to last month. any ideas though?

I just tried it again, this time suspend from gnome menu top right, and those lines came up briefly then suspend worked, and resumed ok.

Comment: and suspend lid closed worked ok. so those lines not relevant to the locking up perhaps. though they were not there before either. maybe the 'bandaids' are working.

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; only a kernel from an EOL & HWE kernel stack without clues as to which.

Comment: "20.4.1 wayland 5.19.0-46-generic"   ubuntu version, desktop environment, and kernel version respectively. unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 had two kernel stack options; the GA kernel was 5.4 & the HWE kernel was 5.8.  5.19 is a kernel from Ubuntu 22.10, and is in the last days of being the HWE kernel for 22.04.2 (*as 22.04.3 with it's 6.2 kernel is to be released in a few hours!*)  Your mix of values makes little sense to me, as 20.04.1 would mean either 5.4 or 5.8 kernel and not 5.19, so my guess is you're not using Ubuntu most likely.

Comment: uname -r gives me 5.19.0-46-generic
lsb_release -a gives me Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
and cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager gives me   /usr/sbin/gdm3

what other commands do you know that would give you the information you need?
in any case no lockups now. It might even have something to do with running the laptop, still with a battery charge but with a mains input off a truck battery and transformer and low voltage .